# AutoWire argument in a new service

Tags: symfony, service, autowired, symfony5

I have the following service :

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use ADOConnection;

class ADOdbConnection
{
    /**
     * AdodbConnection constructor.
     * @param $host
     * @param $user
     * @param $pwd
     * @param $db
     */
    public function __construct($host, $user, $pwd, $db_name)
    {
        $db = ADONewConnection('odbc');
        $db->connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db_name);
    }

    /**
     * Testing current connection
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function testConnection()
    {
        return $this->db->IsConnected();
    }

}
```

Very simple, and the pending configuration into config/services.yaml :

```
// config/services.yaml
services:
   //... -- 15 lines -- //
   App\Services\ADOdbConnection:
        arguments:
            $host: '111.11.11.11'
            $user: 'ROOT'
            $pwd: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_W2_PASSWORD)%'
            $db_name: 'CUSTOMER'
```

(See full [config/services.yaml](https://gist.github.com/Vin57/040245c96a74ded4b75064d7f268cb38))

In my controller i got this :

```
public function index(ADOdbConnection $ADOdbConnection)
    {
        dump($ADOdbConnection->testConnection());
}
```

And the result is this error :

```
Cannot resolve argument $ADOdbConnection of "App\Controller\ArticleController::index()": Cannot autowire service "App\Services\ADOdbConnection": argument "$host" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.
```

I have read this doc :

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters

And this one :

- https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-fundamentals/service-config#play

I do the same thing as explain in the symfonycast formation, but i can't get it why it is not working...

I have also read this :

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#services-binding

But i'm not interested  in this feature at the moment.

**EDIT :**

I just figure that i need to define the arguments configuration into my `config/services_dev.yaml` but to me this is a weird since kernel read the file in order

- config/services.yaml
- then config/services_XXX.yaml

So i should not need to define those parameter a second time.

Comment: I just figure that i need to define the arguments configuration into my ``config/services_dev.yaml`` but to me this is a weird since kernel read the file in order 
-> config/services.yaml
-> then config/services_XXX.yaml

Comment: Consider creating a new project and just wire this one service.  The notion that it works with services_dev.yaml possibly indicates that some other code is trying to configure it.  Maybe even a third party compiler pass?  Does seem strange.  Symfony version?  Is this a legacy project?

Comment: Yes it is a standard project i use symfony 5.
I've created this project 3 week ago.
I'll try later to create a new project.

Answer (score 0):

Arguments in `ADOdbConnection` constructor and `service.yaml` should match.
Your 4th parameter is `$db_name`, but it's `$db: 'CUSTOMER'` in YAML.

P.S. I don't think you need `service_dev.yml` for this issue.

Comment: I've edit my services.yaml file to match constructor parameter name, and i have remove services_dev.yaml configuration for this services. Now i still have the same error :(

Comment: Could you provide full config/services.yaml file? You can use https://gist.github.com/ for this

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Vin57/040245c96a74ded4b75064d7f268cb38
Can you see it ?

Comment: Really weird, it's working in my local env. So configuration and class are totally fine. Maybe it's cache issue? Try `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`. And I don't really understand why file `service_dev.yml` is working for you.

Comment: This still not working even after clearing the cache, sad me